# Alfresco - Storing every single form labels as custom content

Tags: alfresco, ecm, content-model

Our team is building a rather large enterprise application.  Alfresco is the ECM that will be storing all the content.

However, we're being told that they literally mean ALL static content, including small things like form labels, such as "Gender", "Login", "Submit" because:

1. developers do not want to hard-code in any static values into their code.
2. some customers that use our software are willing to pay additional fee for having flexibility to relabel those labels to "Sex", "Log On", "Save".

Setting aside performance implication (which they probably addressed through periodic indexing jobs), is there a precedent for storing micro content like this in Alfresco?  Is there a reference / guide that I can refer to for this?

What is the best way to content modeling and create content type of this scale, and also allow for customer specific overrides/customization?

I know this is an unusual topic, so your thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: so with "rather large enterprise application" you don't mean an application based on Alfresco but an application which uses Alfresco as a generic content storage and form lables may be one specific type and use case for content?

Comment: @HeikoRobert Yes that is correct.  Alfresco is used as a generic content storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all about internationalization in Alfresco documentation : [Internationalization (i18n)](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-I18N.html)

the [Working With Custom Content Types in Alfresco](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html) tutorial created by Jeff Potts, is a very good beginning for content modeling

Comment: i18n is something we also need to account for as well, but it's a separate issue.  My response to Heiko Robert above is my primary challenge at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In alfresco if you don't wanted to hard code labels then override properties or message files , the labels are taken from message/properties file so you need to override the properties file.
You can override your message/properties file at run time place the file with same path in this folder

`Company Home> Data Dictionary> Messages`